# Call to TaskFactory.StartNew() with parameters errors with "reference to non-shared member requires an object reference "

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, task-parallel-library, taskfactory

The code segment has the error   "reference to non-shared member requires an object reference "  in Line 7. I am using a MS example to work through this, so it should work. Thanks!

```
Sub main()
    Dim TokenSource As New CancellationTokenSource()
    Dim token As CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token
    Dim TaskX As Task
    Dim tasks As New ConcurrentBag(Of Task)()
    MessageBox.Show("In Module taskStore running Main subroutine")
    TaskX = TaskFactory.StartNew(Sub() DoSomeWork(1, token), token)
    tasks.Add(t)
End Sub

Sub DoSomeWork(ByVal taskNum As Integer, ByVal ct As CancellationToken)
    If ct.IsCancellationRequested = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("TaskX cancelled before it got started")
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    End If
    Dim maxIterations As Integer = 100

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim factory As New TaskFactory / factory.StartNew(...)

Comment: Can you link to this "MS example"?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-task-and-its-children

Comment: Got it! Thank you, Hans!

Comment: The example is in C#, not VB.NET. Instead of trying to convert every example and Github project to VB.NET you should probably switch to C#. Despite Microsoft's efforts, *developers* abandoned VB.NET, so eventually even Microsoft stopped posting examples in both languages. That's why you can't find docs or examples in VB.NET. Not because MS abandoned it (all docs were in both languages for almost 20 years) but because *developers* had abandoned it by 2012. Besides, you need to understand C# to be able to convert code to VB.NET

Comment: [DotNetNuke switches to C#](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134946/dotnetnuke-switches-to-c-) should give you an idea of just how strong developer feelings were **against VB.NET** by 2011 - DNN was a content management framework written in VB.NET whose maintainer refused to convert it to C# claiming all sorts of reasons. So someone went and converted it anyway, proving the objections unfounded and forcing the maintainer to accept the coup or lose control of the project as all users were ready to switch to the converted project

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Check your settings.  I see VB.  There's a language dropdown in the upper right that may not be obvious if you're not looking for it.

Comment: @Craig that dropdown used to be on the example itself. The VB.NET example is correct too - `Task.Factory.StartNew`, not `TaskFactory.StartNew`

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to uses :

```
t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() DoSomeWork(1, token), token)
```

not

```
t = TaskFactory.StartNew(Sub() DoSomeWork(1, token), token)
```

The [Task.Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.factory?view=net-6.0) property returns a default TaskFactory instance that can be used to call the `StartNew` object method.

That method isn't used since 2012 when `Async/Await` and `Task.Run` were introduced. That's explained in [the docs as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.factory?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Task.Run method provides the easiest way to create a Task object with default configuration values.

Right now the oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.5.2 but even that will [go out of support in April 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework), in just 3 months. Your code should target 4.6.2 at least, although 4.7.1 or 4.8 would be better